# Error getting data from second db context instantiated 'through' an interface

Tags: entity-framework, interface, ef-code-first

Currently working with codefirst v5 on .net 4.5

I have 1 'master' context which includes a locations table called 'Geonames' (snippet below)

```
public class CoreContext : DbContext
            : base("Conn")
{
    public DbSet<GeoName> GeoNames { get; set; }
}
```

The reference here is simply to be able to manage migrations on the table.

Site will have the ability to 'plug-in' different location providers and the geonames table is there to provide a local provider implementation.
The provider is set in the configuration of the website simply setting the classname and namespace of the actual implementation.
It uses an interface like this (simplified)

```
public interface ILocationProvider
{
    IEnumerable<Location> LocationsByName(String Name);
}
```

The concrete implementation is instantiated as below (simplified)

```
    public static ILocationProvider GetLocationProvider()
    {

        ILocationProvider Provider = null;

        Provider = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("{selected namespace.classname}")) as ILocationProvider;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        if (Provider == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Could not create an instance of the location Provider");
        }

        return Provider;
    }
```

The concrete implementation is as follows(simplified)

```
public class LocalLocationProvider : ILocationProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Location> LocationsByName(string Name)
    {
        List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();

        using (var db = new LocalLocationContext())
        {   

            foreach (var item in db.GeoNames.Where(X => X.Name.Contains(Name)))
            {   
                locations.Add(
                    new Location { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name, GeoLocation = item.GeoLocation }
                );
            }
        }

        return locations;
    }

    private class LocalLocationContext : DbContext
    {
        public LocalLocationContext()
            : base("Conn")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<LocalLocationContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<GeoName> GeoNames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The concrete implementation instantiates just fine and I call the method 'LocationsByName' .. but here the trouble starts. When the code line below executes

```
foreach (var item in db.GeoNames.Where(X => X.Name.Contains(Name)))
{
  ..
}
```

I get the following error.

```
Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

    [SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753986
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5296058
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1379
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +437
```

I have tried to instantiate 'LocalLocationContext' without using the 'Activator.CreateInstance()' method I can query the data just fine.

To me it seems obvious that it has got something to do with how I get my actual implemention of the location provider just can't spot what the error or issue is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure the connection is defined correctly in web.config or app.config

Comment: Yes.. the implementation is working if I instantiate it directly.